# SQL query to find employee points in a month always less than 75

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an employee table it was updated weekly once, it is having the grade points 1 - 100, i need to pick the employees who are all got always less than 75 points in the month(last four weeks). If any one of the week the employee scored more than 75 then he should not picked.

Can someone help, how to find this using the SQL query?

Employee table contains the name, id, grade, salary, reportdate.

Records are inserted in weekly basis.

Every Monday employee records are inserted, the report date will be the Monday date.

Now i need to pick the employees who are all have grade less than 75 in a month(four weeks data) date present in the reportDate column. If any one of the week employee have grade greater than 75 then employee is not eligible.

```
'employee', 'CREATE TABLE `employee` (\n  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `reportDate` date NOT NULL,\n  `salary` double NOT NULL,\n  `grade` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

I am using mysql database.

[image]

Here the employee 'a' only eligible because he has grade less than 75 in all four weeks,'b' is not eligible in one week his grade is greater than 75. I need to find only the eligible employee all records.

the output should come like this

[image]

Comment: Can you post your schema / code that you have so far?

Comment: A Schema & previous attempt would help us help you.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add tags for the database you are actually using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Also explain **Last four weeks**. Are these calculated after the **EndOfMonth** or  could it be the **15 days of this month and 15 days of previous month**

Comment: @MalikAsif, that was actually explained. Last for weeks means any time earlier than now() but not earlier than 28 days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query selects the id and name from a joined relation, which holds employees having at least a `grade` in the last four weeks and all grades in the period being less than 75.

```
select emp.id, emp.name
from emp
join grade
on emp.id = grade.emp_id and grade.date > DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 28 DAY)
group by emp.id
having max(grade) < 75
```

EDIT:

Taken into account the structure of the `table`, this is the improved query:

```
select employee.id, employee.name
from employee
where employee.reportDate > DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 28 DAY)
group by employee.id
having max(employee.grade) < 75
```

Please, let me know if you encounter any problems, the code is untested.

EDIT2:

Based on the edit done for the question, this is the new query:

```
select emp1.id, emp1.name, emp1.reportDate, emp1.salary, emp1.grade
from employee emp1
where emp1.reportDate > DAT_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 28 DAY)
  and not exists (select emp2.id
                  from emp2
                  where emp1.name = emp2.name
                    and emp2.reportDate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 28 DAY)
                    and emp2.grade >= 75)
order by salary desc
```

However, Your database needs some [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms), to achieve normal form, one flaw is [redundancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_redundancy#In_database_systems) (repeated `name` and `salary` values), the second is that in a table called `employee`, the single way one can actually identify an employee is by `name`, which leads to the third poblem: [inconsistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency), in particular, when `salary` is changed (which will affect the order); or when the `name` is changed (wedding/divorce, for example), when the very same employee will be reported in two different names.

Suggested changes in your database structure:

- rename the `employee` table to `report`
- `create` an `employee` `table` where each record represents an employee (`id`, `name`, `salary`)
- add a `foreign key` to the `report` table which will reference the `employee` table
- remove the `name` column from the `report` `table`
- `create` a `salaries` `table`, which will have an `id`, an `employee_id` which will reference the `employee` table and a `salary` column
- remove the `salary` column from the `report` `table`
- refactor all the affected code

Comment: Is it preference to put the grade date logic in the on clause rather than the where clause - or is there some performance difference?

Comment: @StanShaw, this can be answered by effectively analyzing the query plan. However, it is more elegant to include where conditions into the on clause, which is a local where (of the join relation filtering records not meant to be there ASAP) rather than into the where clause, which, by definition is the global filter for the final, already joined relation. In reality, things are different, due to optimization, but if we keep our code elegant, we minimize the chances of undesired surprises on production environment.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Understood and agreed with respect to code organization.  I was just curious if there was an additional performance benefit.

Comment: Hi Lajos and all thanks for your replies, i have the grade in employee table itself.

Comment: @user2724215, please add the table structure to your question. My code was written "blindly", without knowlegde of your actual structure. With this additional information I can still only guess the structure, which prevents me from updating my answer.

Comment: @user2724215, please, add the table structure to your question. Run show create table employee; and paste the result into your question. Without the structure I cannot help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108964/discussion-between-user2724215-and-lajos-arpad).

Comment: Hi lajos, i updated the question please check, the query you given not satisfies the need, sorry i didn't write the question clear in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub query in the `WHERE` clause with a `DATEDIFF` function to define the date ranges.

```
SELECT name
FROM employeetable
WHERE (SELECT grade 
       FROM employeetable 
       WHERE AND DATEDIFF(mm,datefield, GETDATE())=1
       AND DATEDIFF(yy,datefield, GETDATE())=0) < 75
OR (((SELECT grade 
      FROM employeetable 
      WHERE AND DATEDIFF(ww,datefield, GETDATE())=1
      AND DATEDIFF(yy,datefield, GETDATE())=0) < 75)
    AND
    ((SELECT grade 
      FROM employeetable 
      WHERE AND DATEDIFF(ww,datefield, GETDATE())=2
      AND DATEDIFF(yy,datefield, GETDATE())=0) < 75)
    AND
    ((SELECT grade 
      FROM employeetable 
      WHERE AND DATEDIFF(ww,datefield, GETDATE())=3
      AND DATEDIFF(yy,datefield, GETDATE())=0) < 75)
    AND
    ((SELECT grade 
      FROM employeetable 
      WHERE AND DATEDIFF(ww,datefield, GETDATE())=4
      AND DATEDIFF(yy,datefield, GETDATE())=0) < 75))
```

Comment: Good lord!  That is a lot of code for a pretty easy problem.  Check out Lajos Arpad's answer.